# How can I change the twistie icon in view control?

Tags: xpages

Is there a way how can I change the twistie icon in view control? I mean the icon used for expand/collapse buttons for categories.

In HTML source I can see, its not managed by CSS, so I can't change it this way. It seems to be rather hardcoded.

```
<img id="view:_id1:viewPanel1:2:viewColumn1__shrink:1.1.1.1img" alt="expanded" src="/domjava/xsp/theme/common/images/collapse.gif">
```

Comment: Sorry to bother comnunity, just found it in ViewColumn property

Answer (score 7, accepted):

click the ViewColumn and look for Expand/Collapse Image in the all properties view :-)